# Why is EasySplashScreen icon so small (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, mipmaps, android-mipmap

I added the splash screen with the EasySplashScreen library after I created a good portion of my app, but it seems that no matter what I do the icon remains really small. I have tried reimporting the mipmap image, and during the import process, choosing different sizes on the size dropdown and having it display the logo in sizes like xxhdpi or xxxhdpi, but whenever I run it, it always remains the regular hdpi size. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: please add some code, otherwise it's difficult to understand what's the problem

Comment: There isn't any code that applies. I would like to have it in a larger size and have went into the mipmap editor to choose xxhdpi or xxxhdpi, but it only uses regular hdpi.